# Use decision rules to split other data

Tags: r, weka, decision-tree, rweka

I am looking for an elegant solution to use the decision rules created in one dataset (for a example your training set) to split the data of another dataset (e.g test data) according to these rules.

Look at this example:

```
# Load PimaIndiansDiabetes dataset from mlbench package
library("mlbench")
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes")
## Split in training and test (2/3 - 1/3)
idtrain <- c(sample(1:768,512))
PimaTrain <-PimaIndiansDiabetes[idtrain,]
Pimatest <-PimaIndiansDiabetes[-idtrain,]

m1 <- RWeka::J48(as.factor(as.character(PimaTrain$diabetes)) ~ .,
                 data = PimaTrain[,-c(9)],
                 control = RWeka::Weka_control(M = 10, C= 0.25))
```

Which gives following output:

```
> m1
J48 pruned tree
------------------

glucose <= 154
|   age <= 28
|   |   glucose <= 118: neg (157.0/11.0)
|   |   glucose > 118
|   |   |   pressure <= 52: pos (10.0/3.0)
|   |   |   pressure > 52: neg (54.0/12.0)
|   age > 28
|   |   glucose <= 103: neg (54.0/10.0)
|   |   glucose > 103
|   |   |   mass <= 41.3: neg (129.0/55.0)
|   |   |   mass > 41.3: pos (12.0/1.0)
glucose > 154: pos (96.0/19.0)

Number of Leaves  :     7

Size of the tree :  13
```

Based on these rules you will have 7 groups (or leaves). What I am looking for is to apply these rules (so not re-training a decision tree) on the test data *Pimatest* so that actually every datapoint can be appointed to one of the 7 groups indicated with a new variable *group*.

the output would look like this:

```
head(Pimatest)
   pregnant glucose pressure triceps insulin mass pedigree age diabetes group
3         8     183       64       0       0 23.3    0.672  32      pos     7
4         1      89       66      23      94 28.1    0.167  21      neg     1
6         5     116       74       0       0 25.6    0.201  30      neg     5
7         3      78       50      32      88 31.0    0.248  26      pos     1
8        10     115        0       0       0 35.3    0.134  29      neg     5
11        4     110       92       0       0 37.6    0.191  30      neg     5
```

I currently have a working solution which is coded really bad so that's why I am looking for an elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: Those 7 groups will be associated with 7 unique predicted values (of your target variable). Why don't you use `predict` on your new dataset and then use the predicted values to group your rows/data?

Comment: This is a simple toy example. I am not sure whether in all cases you will have unique predicted values for all different groups. Moreover the question remains how you afterwards link those groups back to the rules.

Comment: Your statement is not correct. The predicted values will give you a probability which is derived from the number of 1's and 0's in a certain leaf node during training. So it is possible that leaf nodes return the same value when predicting for instances even if they are not in the same node.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the reason I always check if the prediction values are unique before I apply what I described before. It just happens to have different values due to decimal points. However, the model you build might have an argument that returns not only the predicted value, but the terminal node/group number as well. Something like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171915/r-classification-ctree-party-testing-sample-and-leaf-attribution-with-unba/172088 where you can use `predict(model, newdata=dt_test, type="node")` for this type of tree model.

Comment: The type argument only allows for *probability* or *class* and not for *nodes*. My solution so far is to extract the decision rules as character out of my *m1* decision tree object with the party package and after some bad looking code I can apply it to the new data. This does the trick, but I would really like to have an more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to be able to tie each point to the set of rules that classify that point. You can get there by converting the `J48` tree to a `party` tree and using tools from the `partykit` package.

Because you did not set the seed for the random number generator, 
we cannot get exactly the same test/training split that you got.
I will set the seed to make my example reproducible, but even 
though I use your code, my tree will be slightly different than yours.

**Reproducible example** (mostly your code)

```
library(RWeka)
library("mlbench")
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes")

## Split in training and test (2/3 - 1/3)
set.seed(1234)
idtrain <- c(sample(1:768,512))
PimaTrain <-PimaIndiansDiabetes[idtrain,]
Pimatest <-PimaIndiansDiabetes[-idtrain,]

m1 <- RWeka::J48(as.factor(as.character(PimaTrain$diabetes)) ~ .,
                 data = PimaTrain[,-c(9)],
                 control = RWeka::Weka_control(M = 10, C= 0.25))
m1
J48 pruned tree
------------------
glucose <= 122
|   mass <= 26.8: neg (85.0/1.0)
|   mass > 26.8
|   |   pregnant <= 4: neg (137.0/19.0)
|   |   pregnant > 4
|   |   |   glucose <= 106: neg (44.0/10.0)
|   |   |   glucose > 106: pos (24.0/6.0)
glucose > 122
|   glucose <= 157
|   |   age <= 31
|   |   |   age <= 24: neg (30.0/5.0)
|   |   |   age > 24
|   |   |   |   pressure <= 72: pos (16.0/5.0)
|   |   |   |   pressure > 72: neg (22.0/5.0)
|   |   age > 31: pos (78.0/27.0)
|   glucose > 157: pos (76.0/13.0)

Number of Leaves  :     9
Size of the tree :      17
```

My tree had 9 leaves instead of your 7. This is due to the different
instances chosen for the training set. Now we are ready to get the rules.

```
library(partykit)
Pm1 = as.party(m1)
Pm1
Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] glucose <= 122
|   |   [3] mass <= 26.8: neg (n = 85, err = 1.2%)
|   |   [4] mass > 26.8
|   |   |   [5] pregnant <= 4: neg (n = 137, err = 13.9%)
|   |   |   [6] pregnant > 4
|   |   |   |   [7] glucose <= 106: neg (n = 44, err = 22.7%)
|   |   |   |   [8] glucose > 106: pos (n = 24, err = 25.0%)
|   [9] glucose > 122
|   |   [10] glucose <= 157
|   |   |   [11] age <= 31
|   |   |   |   [12] age <= 24: neg (n = 30, err = 16.7%)
|   |   |   |   [13] age > 24
|   |   |   |   |   [14] pressure <= 72: pos (n = 16, err = 31.2%)
|   |   |   |   |   [15] pressure > 72: neg (n = 22, err = 22.7%)
|   |   |   [16] age > 31: pos (n = 78, err = 34.6%)
|   |   [17] glucose > 157: pos (n = 76, err = 17.1%)

Number of inner nodes:    8
Number of terminal nodes: 9
```

This is the same tree as before, but has the advantage that the nodes are labeled. We can also get the rules written out for each leaf.

```
Pm1_rules = partykit:::.list.rules.party(Pm1)
Pm1_rules
                                                                       3 
                                         "glucose <= 122 & mass <= 26.8" 
                                                                       5 
                          "glucose <= 122 & mass > 26.8 & pregnant <= 4" 
                                                                       7 
          "glucose <= 122 & mass > 26.8 & pregnant > 4 & glucose <= 106" 
                                                                       8 
           "glucose <= 122 & mass > 26.8 & pregnant > 4 & glucose > 106" 
                                                                      12 
                "glucose > 122 & glucose <= 157 & age <= 31 & age <= 24" 
                                                                      14 
"glucose > 122 & glucose <= 157 & age <= 31 & age > 24 & pressure <= 72" 
                                                                      15 
 "glucose > 122 & glucose <= 157 & age <= 31 & age > 24 & pressure > 72" 
                                                                      16 
                             "glucose > 122 & glucose <= 157 & age > 31" 
                                                                      17 
                                         "glucose > 122 & glucose > 157"
```

The decisions are written out as rules. The names of the rulesets are the 
numbers of the leaf nodes. To get the rules used for a test point,  you just need to know which leaf node it ends up at. But the `predict` method for party object will give you that.

```
TestPred = predict(Pm1, newdata=Pimatest, type="node")
TestPred
  3   4   5   6   9  12  17  20  22  27  28  29  31  32  33  35  36  38  41  43 
 17   5  16   3  17  17   5   5   7  16   3  16   8  17   3   8   3   7  17   3 
 46  48  50  56  57  60  62  64  65  66  68  70  72  75  76  79  84  95  96  97 
 17   5   3   3  17   5  16  12   8   7   5  15  14   5   3  14   3  12  16   5 
...
```

I truncated the output because it was too long. Now, for example,
we see that the first test point went to node 17. We just need to use that to index into the rule sets. But a little care is needed. The 17 returned by `predict` is a number. The name of the ruleset is a string, so we need to use `as.character` to convert it.

```
Pm1_rules[as.character(TestPred[1])]
                             17 
"glucose > 122 & glucose > 157"
```

We confirm:

```
Pimatest[1,]
  pregnant glucose pressure triceps insulin mass pedigree age diabetes
3        8     183       64       0       0 23.3    0.672  32      pos
```

So yes,  `glucose > 122` AND `glucose > 157`

You can get the rules for the other test points in the same way.

Comment: Great answer! Can I just confirm that this can be done only using `partykit` and not `party`? I mean that even if I have a tree model built using package `party` I'll need to use `partykit` to get those rules, right?

Comment: @AntoniosK I don't know anything comparable to `partykit:::.list.rules.party` in party. If you want the rules, I think that you must use partykit.